# selenium chromedriver - Twitter detects suspicious activity

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I have an automated daily task with `RSelenium` in the cloud. This task consists of logging (required) into *www.twitter.com* and make a webflow navigation. Instead, Twitter detects this logging as suspicious activity.

How could I avoid it? **My IP is static**. I think one way to solve it would be using the webdriver.remote.sessionid so that Twitter does not consider me as a new user in each task iteration. 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rather than circumventing, you could also consider abiding by the terms of service instead of abusing it.

Comment: It is easy to detect Selenium automation. You can imagine that Twitter has to cope with a lot of unwanted bots. If you want to use an automated daily task, Twitter provides an api to do that: https://developer.twitter.com/.

Comment: I just need to download the statistics file from my account. So I can not use the Twitter API.